# What does ${_csrf} do? Is this an implicit EL object?

Tags: java, jsp

I'm going over some source code and trying to figure out where `_csrf` came from. As far as I can guess, it looks like an implicit EL object. Maybe related to authentication and spring security.

The below is the code that contains `_csrf`.

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

**What does ${_csrf} do? Is this an implicit EL object?**

Comment: What this code has to do with Java?

Comment: @KhanSaab JSP is Java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cross-site request forgery, also known as one-click attack or session riding and abbreviated as CSRF (sometimes pronounced sea-surf) or XSRF, is a type of malicious exploit of a website where unauthorized commands are transmitted from a user that the web application trusts.

This input protects form from csrf attacks by adding a special csrf token to all of your page requests

Check this out:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-csrf

Answer (score 6):

[As described in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-include-csrf-token), the `_csrf` variable is provided by Spring Security. A better approach in JSP is to use the `csrfInput` tag; Thymeleaf includes this automatically and doesn't require including it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Well, This is an object that belongs to a class that has implemented [CsrfToken](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.15.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/csrf/CsrfToken.html) Interface.

This object has been set as a `request parameter` by Spring security.

and if you're going to read it in another place like Controller, You can use this code for loading the token from incoming `HttpServletRequest` object.

```
CsrfToken theToken = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository().loadToken(req);
```